# profile expression kit for iOS (FBSDKProfileExpressionKit)

Tags: ios, fbsdk

I am unable to find `FBSDKProfileExpressionKit for iOS` of facebook in 
https://developers.facebook.com/products/profile-expression-kit
. Kindly help!

P.S. I want to download the SDK from reliable site only.

Comment: Here you are https://developers.facebook.com/docs/profile-expression-kit/ios

Comment: Only documentation is present on this page, not the SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the reply from `facebook`:

Unfortunately we are no longer offering this SDK for download.

I apologize for any confusion our docs have caused, we are working to update them.